# Fewest operations to 100

Tags: code-golf, integer, integer-partitions, expression-building

## Overview

Given a list of digits, find the fewest operations to make 100

## Input

A string of digits, which may or may not be in numerical order. The order of the digits cannot be changed, however plus (+) or minus (-) operators may be added between each so that the total sum is equal to 100.

## Output

The number of operators added, followed by the full sequence of digits and operators. The two can be separated by a space, tab, or new line sequence.

## Examples

**valid**

Input: `123456789`
Output: `3 123–45–67+89`

**Invalid**
Input: `123456789`
Output:
`6
1+2+34-5+67-8+9`
(There are ways of solving this with fewer operations)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70361/official-dyalog-apl-2016-year-game)

Comment: Do we have to use all of the digits? Can we only use `+` and `-`? Can we assume we will always be able to make `100` from the input?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder All digits must be used, and must remain in the same order. The only thing that can be changed is adding + and -.

Comment: Some more test cases would be much welcome.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to lead to at least one solution? If not, what's the expected output?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, there will always be at least 1 possible solution

Comment: Is output such as `{3, "123-45-67+89"}` (use language-specified tuple structure) acceptable?

Comment: Can you confirm that signs cannot be prepended to the first digit? That is, given input `299399`, would `-299+399` be valid?

Comment: May we use our languages native operators (or even any alternative but consistent characters) in the output?

Comment: Is '0' a digit? E.g., is '10808' a valid input? Is '1 108-08' a valid response?

Comment: @KeyuGan yes, as long as the two components are obviously seperate

Comment: @LuisMendo no, signs can only be added between digits

Comment: @ChasBrown yes, 0 is a digit

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>153</s> 176 bytes

*EDIT: In non-strict mode, JS interprets 0-prefixed numerical expressions as octal (e.g. `017` is parsed as 15 in decimal). This is a fixed version that supports leading zeros.*

```js
let f =

s=>[...Array(3**(l=s.length,l-1))].map((_,n)=>m=eval((x=s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c+['','+','-'][o=(n/3**i|0)%3,j-=!o,o],j=l)).replace(/\b0+/g,' '))-100|j>m?m:(S=x,j),m=l)&&m+' '+S

console.log(f("123456789"))
console.log(f("20172117"))
```

Comment: Nice, what about 20172117 as input?

Comment: @LuisMendo Actually, I think the expected answer is `2-017-2+117`. But `017` is an octal notation in JS, which gives 15 in decimal. So my current code only finds `2-0-17-2+117`. I'll try to address that problem later today.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, I hadn't seen that other solution. Removing my comment

Comment: @mdahmoune Thanks for bringing this up. Now fixed.

Comment: `3**(l=s.length,l-1)` => `3**~-(l=s.length)`

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
n'+-'OhZ^!t2\s&SZ)"G@!vXzU100=?@z3M.
```

The test case takes about 6 seconds in TIO.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P09dW1fdPyMqTrHEKKZYLThKU8ndQbEsoirU0MDA1t6hythX7/9/dUMjYxNTM3MLS3UA)

#### How it works

```
n        % Implicitly input a string. Number of elements, say k
'+-'     % Push this string
Oh       % Append char 0. This is treated like ' ' (space)
Z^       % Cartesian power of the three-char string '+- ' raised to k.
         % Gives a matrix where each row is a Cartesian k-tuple
!        % Transpose
t        % Duplicate
2\       % Modulo 2. This turns '+' and '-' into 1, and ' ' into 0
s        % Sum of each column: number of '+' and '-' symbols
&S       % Sort and push the indices of the sorting
Z)       % Apply as column indices. This sorts the columns (k-tuples)
         % by the number of '+' and '-' they contain
"        % For each column, i.e. each k-tuple formed by '+', '-' and ' '
  G      %   Push input string again
  @!     %   Push k-tuple as row vector (string)
  v      %   Concatenate vertically into a 2×k char array
  Xz     %   Remove space (and char 0). Gives a string as result. In this
         %   process, the 2×k array is linearized in column major order 
         %   (down, then across). So the '+' and '-' signs are between 
         %   digits of the input, or at the end
  U      %   Convert to number. This performs the operation determined by
         %   by the '+' and '-' signs and returns the result. A trailing
         %   '+' or '-' sign makes the input invalid, which causes an
         %   empty result
  100=   %   Is it equal to 100?
  ?      %   If so
    @    %     Push current k-tuple
    z    %     Number of nonzeros, i.e. of '+' and '-' signs
    3M   %     Push linearized string without spaces again
    .    %     Break for loop
         %   Implicit end
         % Implicit end
         % Implicitly dispplay stack
```

Comment: Great, what about 299399 as input?

Comment: @mdahmoune `299399` has no solution and is hence [not a valid input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129782/fewest-operations-to-100#comment320187_129782) (the operators were specified to go "between" the digits, that input would require `-299+399` where the `-` is not between digits).

Comment: @mdahmoune If the signs can only be inserted _between_ the digits (as the challenge text says), I think there is no solution. If they can also be prepended to the first digit, the solution is `-299+399`, and in that case I need [a small change in my code](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P09dW1fdPyMqTrHEKKZYLThKU8lB0b0soirU0MDA1t6hythX7/9/dSNLS2NLS3UA). I've asked the OP for clarification

Comment: Also noteworthy that if it were meant to be both before *and* between then the example `123456789` should have an operator count of `4` not `3`.

Comment: @mdahmoune The OP has confirmed that signs can only be between digits. So my code is correct and `299399` is an invalid input because, as the OP has also clarified, every input should have at least one solution

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
L’⁾+_ṗż@€
ŒṖÇ€ẎµFV=ȷ2µÐfLÞḢFṄḟ³L
```

A full program which displays using the Jelly operators (`_` instead of `-`).

*Note:* To show `-` in the output instead of `_` (not a requirement) add `⁾_-y` between `F` and `Ṅ` (`⁾_-` is a character pair literal `['_','-']` and `y` is the dyadic "translate" atom).

#### How?

```
L’⁾+_ṗż@€ - Link 1, form all sums from a partition: list of lists of characters
                                     e.g. ["12","345","67"]
L         - length                        3
 ’        - decremented                   2
  ⁾+_     - literal ['+','_']
     ṗ    - Cartesian power               ["++","+_","_+","__"]
      ż@€ - zip for €ach (swap @rguments) ["12+345+67","12+345_67","12_345+67","12_345_67"]

ŒṖÇ€ẎµFV=ȷ2µÐfLÞḢFṄḟ³L - Main link: list of characters
ŒṖ                     - all partitions
  Ç€                   - call the last link (1) as a monad for €ach
    Ẏ                  - tighten (flatten by 1 level)
     µ     µÐf         - filter keep if:
      F                -   flatten
       V               -   evaluate as Jelly code (perform the sum)
         ȷ2            -   literal 100
        =              -   equal?
               Þ       - sort by:
              L        -  length
                Ḣ      - head
                 F     - flatten
                  Ṅ    - print that and a newline
                   ḟ³  - filter out the characters from the input
                     L - length (number of operators)
                       - implicit print
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVIArf9qZWxsef//TOKAmeKBvitf4bmXxbxA4oKsCsWS4bmWw4figqzhuo7CtUZWPci3MsK1w5BmTMOe4biiRuG5hOG4n8KzTP///yIxMjM0NTY3ODki)**

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>166</s> 171 bytes

```php
for(;$n<3**$e=strlen($x=$argn);eval("return $s;")-100?:$r[]=sprintf("%2d $s",strlen($s)-$e))for($i=0,$s="",$k=$n++;a&$c=$x[$i];$k/=3)$s.="+-"[$i++?$k%3:2].$c;echo min($r);
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf76e4cfc14b2a6b2f823032f158a22424df7c10).

uses formatted numbers to sort the results -->
may print leading blanks (and may fail for input with more than 99 digits; increase the number at `%2d` to fix).

**no more than 10 digits, 161 bytes**

```php
for(;$n<3**$e=strlen($x=$argn);eval("return $s;")-100?:$r[]=(strlen($s)-$e)." $s")for($i=0,$s="",$k=$n++;a&$c=$x[$i];$k/=3)$s.="+-"[$i++?$k%3:2].$c;echo min($r);
```

**breakdown**

```php
for(;$n<3**$e=strlen($x=$argn); # loop $n up
    eval("return $s;")-100?:        # 2. evaluate term, if 100 then
                                    # prepend number of operations, add to results
        $r[]=sprintf("%2d $s",strlen($s)-$e)
)
                                # 1. create term
    for($i=0,$s="",$k=$n++;         # init variables, increment $n
        a&$c=$x[$i];$k/=3)          # loop through digits/operator index
        $s.="+-"[$i++?$k%3:2].$c;   # prepend operator for base-3 digit (nothing for 2)
echo min($r);                   # print lowest result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2], <s>164</s> 158 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
f=lambda N:min((len(s)-len(N),s)for s in(''.join(sum(zip(N,p+('',)),()))for p in product(('+','-',''),repeat=len(N)-1))if eval(s)==100)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1bCsIwEEX/u4r8ZcamYvrQRugWuodqE4w0D9JU0M3XqCB6YbhwOMz193hxtlxXFZwhOsoQnZtmoo13IW4y1U2DOY0D6Y9GW4BJWpixeFWPbEblAkm2BUq3V5d6Xgw8tIee@TxBhsgA8e355BEf3LicIwDNKaNFOoosSC@H2H2@FhxRKyJvw5Smuo7vdrj6oG0kCigvq7rZH1pBMfvCSohS/BHRHvZNXZX8F/JPElqf)

Take N as a string of digits; returns a tuple (numOps, expressionString).

Basically the same approach as others; uses itertools.product to construct the individual "cases" e.g. for N=='1322', a "case" would be `('-','','+')`, and would evaluate '1-32+2'.

Throws an ValueError if the input is invalid (but I think OP gauranteed no invalid inputs).

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 36 bytes

```
~cịᵐ{|ṅ}ᵐ{+100&{ℕṫ,"+"↻|ṫ}ᵐcbE&kl;E}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy754e7uh1snVNc83NlaC2JoGxoYqFU/apn6cOdqHSVtpUdtu4Fyq0FyyUmuatk51q61//8rGRoZm5iamVtYKv2PAgA)

More than half of this is to get the output format right though. The actual core logic is only:

## 15 bytes

```
~cịᵐ{|ṅ}ᵐ.+100∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy754e7uh1snVNc83NlaC2ToaRsaGDzqWP7/v5KhkbGJqZm5haXS/ygA)

This returns a list like [123,–45,–67,89]. The expression is the sum of the elements, and the number of operators is 1 less than the length of the list.

`~cLhℕ∧100~+L` almost works for 12 bytes ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy7ZJ@NRy9RHHcsNDQzqtH3@/zc1MDMwNPgfBQA)) - but it's too slow to handle full 9 digit input on TIO, and more importantly, it fails for inputs like `10808` - Brachylog is too smart to split numbers to have leading zeros, so doesn't see the [108, -08] partition.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>256</s> <s>230</s> <s>208</s> <s>205</s> <s>172</s> <s>171</s> <s>170</s> 165 bytes, iterative method

- **33** thanks to Chas Brown
- One saved byte when replacing `len(a)` by `w`
- One saved byte when replacing `z-=1;d=z` by `d=z=z-1`

```python
q=[];a=input()
w=len(a);z=n=3**w
while z-n/3:
 d=z=z-1;j=0;b=''
 while d:r=d%3;d/=3;b+=a[j]+chr(r+43)*(d>0!=r-1);j+=1
 if eval(b)==100:q+=[(len(b)-w,b)]
print min(q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3BDoIgAIfxO09Bbi2QnBKdZP9exHmAsIkzUma5eHlb87v@Dt/0XfpXuGzbjKbVBj5M74VxsmLsAjNcJwSoPF/J2vuxo6kIpaoJdUhIhdQDKm1xOhG6u6sj3FFpV0JpK2CaoRX3PrIorornzN2qA2IhuR4EJKH@QbuPGZnlgKyqehZo2H9tebGeLW/JFH1Y6NMHNvNty@Re9gM)

**Little explanation**
Using the representation in base 3, the code interleaves the digits with the operators {'+','-',concatenation} according to all possible combinations.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 167 bytes, recursive method

```python
def f(s):
 if len(s)==1:return[s]
 b=s[0];q=[]
 for z in f(s[1:]):q+=[b+'+'+z,b+'-'+z,b+z]
 return q
a=input()
print min((len(x)-len(a),x)for x in f(a)if eval(x)==100)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NCoMwEITveYqll2ZRQe1/Sp4keFCa0ICNGmOxvny6Qfbw7cLszIy/8B5cHeNLGzB8RsHAGui1o13KSngdFu/U3DDo5KzK5jlJRYcZPGxgXXpSlWhQTJlUXXak2XJisXMj7e4BE2uldeMSOLLRWxfgYx3nKWvFIqHFfMXkvO7OLVIX/W17ElCZssQYD1V9Ol@ut/vj8Ac)

**Some outputs**

```python
"399299"    --> (1, '399-299')
"987654321" --> (4, '98-76+54+3+21')
"1111111"   --> (3, '1+111-1-11')
```

Comment: I like the use of divmod! A few golfs I can see: replace `list(input())` with just `input()`, since a string is already iterable to save 6 bytes; replace `b.count('+')+b.count('-')` with `len(b)-len(a)` to save 12 bytes; and replace `chr(r+43)` with `chr(r+43)*(d>0!=r-1)` and then you can delete the line `b=b[:-1].replace(',','')` to save net 15 bytes (`(d>0!=r-1)` is equivalent to `(d>0 and 0!=r-1)`).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 136 <del>146</del> <del>149</del> <del>156</del> <del>165</del> <del>166</del> bytes

```
#&@@Sort[{StringLength@#-e+9!(ToExpression@#-100)^2,#}&/@StringJoin/@(Riffle[b,#]&)/@Tuples[{"","+","-"},(e=Length[b=Characters@#])-1]]&
```

Returns `{3, 123-45-67+89}` for example.

The test case takes about 0.09 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>180</s> 178 bytes

```hs
m#[a]=[[a]]
m#(b:r)|s<-m#r=m(b:)=<<[s,m('+':)s,m('-':)s]
o '-'=(-)
o _=(+)
(p:r)?a|[(b,s)]<-lex r=s?o p a(read b)
_?a=a
g s=minimum[(sum[1|c<-t,c<'0'],t)|t<-map#s,('+':t)?0==100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5LisMwEET3OkUTB6wmEtjzn6DGBxEitDMmY8btGEkDWfjujpLN49WiqPrl9DdM07ZJ5TmQLwhKKt0fI67JWakiSUlIzvlkRNeH@ohPsQ8J6grFSFssdiJ9QKWXUu549bo3CYOz03CDSKm7wgKs48A/0KM6dUysLpBIxnmUf/E6FbTr2dlszq5u6mAyrrm84KVK5rmdsWuI2qYJm/A4A8ESxznDHi6wa19e394/Pr@@d9sd) Usage: `g "123456789"` yields `(3,"123-45-67+89")`.

`#` builds a list of all possible terms, `?` evaluates a term and `g` filters those terms which evaluate to 100 and returns the one with the minimal number of operands.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
L’““+“_”ṗ⁸żF¥ⱮV⁼ȷ2ƊƇLÞḢṄḟ⁸L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/nUcPMRw1zgEgbiOMfNcx9uHP6o8YdR/e4HVr6aOO6sEeNe05sNzrWdazd5/C8hzsWPdzZ8nDHfKAKn/@H249Oerhzxv//6oZGxiamZuYWluoA)

Can't say I didn't take a few hints from Jonathan Allan's older answer. ;-)

Compared to his answer, this one is just two bytes shorter (30), not five, if we make the comparison fair due to language updates:

```
L’““+“_”ṗ⁸żF¥Ð€V⁼ȷ2$$ÐfLÞḢṄḟ⁸L
```

If we compare the other way (newer version instead of older), the difference is the same (his becomes 29 bytes, seen below):

```
ŒṖżⱮL’⁾+_ṗƲ$€ẎFV=ȷ2ƲƇLÞḢFṄḟ³L
```