# Find operations required to get result

Tags: code-golf, expression-building

So task is simple, given array of numbers and result, you need to find what operations you need to use on numbers from array , to obtain requested result.

Let's make it simple for start, and allow only basic operations such as: addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Example:

```
Input  : [5,5,5,5,5] 100
Output : 5*5*5-5*5
```

To give some advantage to languages like Java, request is to implement function, not entire program, and result can be return via parameter or print to console.

Code is scored based on amount bytes, and as it's golf code challenge, lowest score wins.

Another requirment is <s>You can get additional -10 points</s> if for array contains only digids, support solutions where you could construct numbers from following digits. 
Ie

```
Input  : [1,2,3,4,5] 0
Output : 12-3-4-5
```

Note that, provided outputs are proposed outputs, some cases might have more than one solution. It's up to you will you provide one or more solutions for given task.

**EDIT:**
Result has to be valid from mathematical point of view, hence division is rational division, not integer, and operation precedence is same as in classical math (first multiplication and division then addition and subtraction).

Comment: Does `*` and `/` have precendence over `+` and `-`? Your two examples contradict each other.

Comment: @LeakyNun well spotted, let me fix it

Comment: Please, in the future, make sure you create percentage-based bounties, for a language, like java, -10 bytes isn't as good as for jelly

Comment: @Bálint thanks for suggestion, i will remember about this in future.

Comment: Or even [avoid bonuses altogether](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/36398)

Comment: I'm sure there have been other very similar questions too: the dupe target I chose was the easiest one to find.

Comment: @PeterTaylor as its duplicate, shall i delete it?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can now that it has an answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor from the other hand, we could argue is it duplicate of one which you mark at. seems like it's similar task, but thera are different winning conditions. that one is `code-challenge` this one is `cod-golf`.

Comment: I have closed the dupe target, because it didn't contain a winning criterion at all. Before I reopen this though, could you clarify whether division is integer division or rational division? Also a word on the order of operations would be good. And as Luis Mendo mentioned, I recommend getting rid of the bonuses. Either require concatenation or don't. (In either case, there's a good chance someone might close it as a dupe of something else, because we've had a lot of these challenges, but they're very tricky to find, due to lack of good keywords.)

Comment: As an example, there's http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6417/8478, which doesn't require concatenation but does ask for parentheses.

Comment: @MartinEnder I added suggested changes,  will you reopen it, or shall o accept provided answer?

Comment: I'm reopening it for now, but there's a chance that some people will think that the lack of support for parentheses doesn't make a sufficient difference over the challenge I linked (or that someone finds something more similar than that one).

Comment: Do the numbers need to be used in order? Also, for future challenges, I heartily recommend using the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where these sorts of issues can be ironed out before posting to Main.

Comment: Are numerical inputs only single digits or can they be multiple digits long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-zero-one-five puzzle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48917/two-zero-one-five-puzzle). Also maybe a duplicate of [Official Dyalog APL 2016 Year Game](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70361/official-dyalog-apl-2016-year-game)

Comment: @mbomb007 it's not a duplicate of either of those. These are arbitrary numerical inputs, and only basic mathematical operations are allowed, they are not supposed to output actual programs.

Comment: @mbomb007 I would say it's not, since that challenge has some serious scoring issues. For example: `Solutions are scored first by the number of expressions they produce and then by their code length in bytes. Hence, a 1000 byte program that produce 80 results will beat a 100 byte program that produces only 79 (though the latter could easily be extended to include the missing results).`

Comment: May I take the arguments in reverse order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

Due to security reasons, `*` and `/` won't evaluate online, but they theoretically work.

```
fqeQvTms.ihQd^"+-*/"lth
```

[Test suite with only `+` and `-`.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqeQvTms.ihQd%5E%22%2B-%22lth&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%5D%2C25%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%2C1&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## TSQL(sqlserver 2016) <s>310</s> <s>294</s> 280 bytes

What a wonderful opportunity to write ugly code:

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max)= '5,5,5'
DECLARE @a varchar(20) = '125'

,@ varchar(max)='';WITH D as(SELECT @a a UNION ALL SELECT STUFF(a,charindex(',',a),1,value)FROM STRING_SPLIT('*,+,./,-,',',')x,d WHERE a like'%,%')SELECT @+=a+','''+REPLACE(a,'.','')+'''),('FROM D WHERE a not like'%,%'EXEC('SELECT y FROM(values('+@+'null,null))g(x,y)WHERE x='+@b)
```

[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/501607/find-operations-required-to-get-result)

Readable:(insertion of decimal point(.) and removal of the same is necessary in order for sql to accept that 4/5 is not 0 - well removal is for the people testing it)

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max)= '5,5,5'
DECLARE @b varchar(20) = '5'

,@ varchar(max)=''
;WITH D as
(
  SELECT @a a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT STUFF(a,charindex(',',a),1,value)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT('*,+,./,-,',',')x,d
  WHERE a like'%,%'
)
SELECT @+=a+','''+REPLACE(a,',','')+'''),('
FROM D
WHERE a not like'%,%'

EXEC('SELECT y FROM(values('+@+'null,null))g(x,y)WHERE x='+@b)
```

This solution can also handle these types of input:

> Input :[1,2,3,4,5] 0 Output : 12-3-4-5

Answer (score 4):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <s>322</s> <s>304</s> 270 bytes

```sql
SELECT o FROM(SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(:1,1,1)||REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(a||SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL*2+1,1),','),','),'_')o,LEVEL l FROM(SELECT SUBSTR('+-*/_',LEVEL,1)a FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<6)CONNECT BY LEVEL<LENGTH(:1)/2)WHERE:2=dbms_aw.eval_number(o)AND l>LENGTH(:1)/2-1;
```

:1 is the list of digits
:2 is the result searched

Un-golfed :

```sql
SELECT o
FROM   (
         SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(:1,1,1)||REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(a||SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL*2+1,1),','),','),'_')o,LEVEL l 
         FROM ( -- Create one row per operator 
                SELECT SUBSTR('+-*/_',LEVEL,1)a FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<6
              ) CONNECT BY LEVEL<LENGTH(:1)/2  -- Create every combination of operators, one per ','
)
WHERE :2=dbms_aw.eval_number(o)  -- filter on result = evaluation
  AND l>LENGTH(:1)/2-1           -- keep only expressions using every digits
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>165</s> 147 bytes

```
a=>o=>(c=[],i=c=>{for(j=0;!((c[j]?++c[j]:c[j]=1)%5);)c[j++]=0},eval(`while(eval(e=(a+'').replace(/,/g,(_,j)=>'+-*/'.charAt(c[~-j/2])))!=o)i(c);e`))
```

Nested `eval`... lovely.

```js
f=a=>o=>(c=[],i=c=>{for(j=0;!((c[j]?++c[j]:c[j]=1)%5);)c[j++]=0},eval(`while(eval(e=(a+'').replace(/,/g,(_,j)=>'+-*/'.charAt(c[~-j/2])))!=o)i(c);e`))
console.log(f([5,5,5,5,5])(100))
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5])(0))
console.log(f([3,4])(0.75))
console.log(f([3,4,5,6])(339))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, <s>170</s> 155 bytes

```
from itertools import*
def f(n,o):print({k for k in[''.join(map(str,sum(j,())))[1:]for j in[zip(x,n)for x in product('+-*/',repeat=len(n))]]if eval(k)==o})
```

Create a generator with all possible orders of the operators, combine that with the numbers, then eval until we get the answer.

https://repl.it/C2F5

Comment: You could save a few characters by replacing `['+','-','*','/']` with `'+-*/'`; since `string`s are iterable, it will treat it just like an `array` with each element being each character in the `string` - so it will act just like you provided it with the array you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>195</s> 186 bytes

Here's an atrocious way of doing it.

```
def x(i,r):
 t=""
 from random import choice as c
 while True:
  for j in i:
   t+=str(j)
   if c([0,1]):t+="."+c("+-/*")
  t=t.strip("+-*/.")+"."
  v=eval(t)
  if v == r:print t
  t=""
```

The function `x` accepts an argument of a `list` and a `result` - `x([1,2,3,4,5], 15)` for example.

The program begins a loop where we begin randomly selecting if we should append `"+", "-", "*", or "/"` between each number, or if we should concatenate them together. This seemed like a more concise option than actually going through permutations and trying every combination to find every result, and although it takes longer to run and is *much* less efficient. (Fortunately that's not a concern in this context!)

It also appends "." to each number to avoid doing integer-rounded operations like `6/4 = 1`. It then `eval`s our expression and determines if the result equal to what we are expecting, and if so, outputs the expression.

This program never exits - it will keep continually outputting results until killed.

**EDIT 1**: Remove unnecessary newlines where one-line `if` statements can be used.

Comment: really funny implementation. but easy to save some more bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCoMwEETvfsWSU6KpVksRhPxFb@JBYsQVNbJurf16G3saZt5j1i8PfinOsyc/A7VLFwLn1RODHTxaB@0GNupcD4dETaqK4DPg5OBFbxcKsBEiRO8JRsAF8BqBE7MxyVFdBXuwsr7rvFFVACIViZUiuWWxUP8HToOM67XFWSpUEpQAduP2dpJ8SeFjN4aqlXBh4PM8ZJ3rp37oQpeNhrxU0Q8 "Python 2 – Try It Online") (176 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, 234 <del>238</del> <del>258</del> bytes

*I'm assuming based on the limitations of the other answers that the number order of the input array is maintained by fiat.*

```
n=length(x)-1
k=n*2+2
p=unique(nchoosek(repmat('*-+/',1,n),n),'rows')
p=[p char(' '*~~p(:,1))]'
c=char(x'*~~p(1,:))
o=p(:,r==cellfun(@eval,mat2cell(reshape([c(:) p(:)]',k,[]),k,0|p(1,:))))
reshape([repmat(x',size(o,2),1) o(:)]',k,[])'
```

This code takes a string of numbers `x`, say `x = '12345'` and a result `r`, say `r = 15` and returns all of the strings of expressions you can evaluate to get `r` from `x` using the four operators.

I've used two different length-equivalent ways of avoiding using `ones(length())`-type or `repmat(length())`-type expressions: `~~p(1,:)` which returns not-not values in `p` (i.e., a list of `1`s the samelength as the first dimension of `p`) and `0|p(:,1)` which returns 0 or is-there-a-value-in-`p` (i.e., a list of `1`s the same length as the second dimension of `p`).

Matlab doesn't have an `nchoosek` *with replacement* method, so I've duplicated the operators the correct number of times, computed the whole space of `nchoosek` for that larger selection of operators, and then used a `unique` call to pare the result down to what it should be (removing equivalent combinations like '***+' and '***+'). I add a trailing space to match the length of the input vector for concatenation purposes and then compose the operator strings with the input strings into the columns of a matrix. I then evaluate the expressions columnwise to get results and find the order of operators that corresponds to those columns with results that match our input `r`.

Test: `x = '12345'`, `r = 15`:

```
1*2*3+4+5 
1+2+3+4+5 
1-2*3+4*5
```

If I had to take an array of double precision values, I'd need `x = num2str(x,'%d');` in order to convert the digits to a string, adding 21 (20 without the `;`) to my score. *The extra bytes were semicolons I left in purely so that anyone running this code won't see their command prompt blow up with long arrays. Since my edit produces a giant pile of warnings about logicals and colon-operands now anyway, I've removed the semicolons in the new version.

Edit 2: Forgot to replace a `2*n+2` with `k`.

Old answer:

```
n=length(x)-1;
p=unique(nchoosek(repmat(['*','-','+','/'],1,n),n),'rows');
l=length(p);
p=[p repmat(' ',l,1)]';
c=reshape([repmat(x',l,1) p(:)]',n*2+2,[]);
o = p(:,r == cellfun(@eval, mat2cell(c,n*2+2,ones(l,1))));
reshape([repmat(x',size(o,2),1) o(:)]',n*2+2,[])'
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

```
a=>o=>eval(`while(eval(e=(a+'').replace(/,/g,_=>'+-*/'.charAt(Math.random()*5)))!=o);e`)
```

Threw in a little randomness to the mix. Much easier than systematically iterating through the combinations.

### Test Suite

```js
f=a=>o=>eval(`while(eval(e=(a+'').replace(/,/g,_=>'+-*/'.charAt(Math.random()*5)))!=o);e`)
console.log(f([5,5,5,5,5])(100))
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5])(0))
console.log(f([3,4])(0.75))
console.log(f([3,4,5,6])(339))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 108 bytes

```php
for(;$i=$argc;eval("$s-$argv[1]?:die(\$s);"))for($s="",$x=$p++;--$i>1;$x/=4)$s.="+-*/"[$s?$x&3:4].$argv[$i];
```

takes input from command line arguments in reverse order. Run with `-r`.

**breakdown**

```php
for(;                   # infinite loop:
    $i=$argc;               # 1. init $i to argument count
    eval("$s-$argv[1]?:"    # 3. if first argument equals expression value,
        ."die(\$s);")       #    print expression and exit
    )
    for($s="",              # 2. create expression:
        $x=$p++;            #    init map
        --$i>1;                 # loop from last to second argument
        $x/=4)                  # C: shift map by two bits
        $s.="+-*/"[$s?$x&3:4]   # A: append operator (none for first operand)
            .$argv[$i];         # B: append operand
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-pa`, 46 bytes

```perl
$"="{,\\*,/,+,-}";$x=<>;($_)=grep$x==eval,<@F>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVapWicmRktHX0dbR7dWyVqlwtbGzlpDJV7TNr0otQDItU0tS8zRsXFws/v/31DBSMFYwUTBlMuAy1QBCrkMDQz@5ReUZObnFf/XLUjMAQA)